# Casting the Poperties of One Object to Another

Tags: java

I am attempting to reduce my code base by using a more generic approach.

Is it possible to assign properties from one object to another?

Here is my code but when I try to use it in my jsp the properties are not found.

One of three object types(shown in the code) are created earlier in the flow of the application. Each has slightly different properties. I would like to use a common object to interface with the jsp instead of three different objects.

```
public class DispositionV8Form {

private String formName = "";
private Object dispositionV8Form = null;

public DispositionV8Form(DispositionV8FormParms dispositionV8FormParms, DispositionListV8 dispositionListV8){

    if(dispositionListV8.getDispositionListV8() != null){
        for(DispositionV8 dispositionV8: dispositionListV8.getDispositionListV8()){

            if(dispositionV8.getDispositionindex() == dispositionV8FormParms.getDispindex()){

                switch(dispositionV8FormParms.getDispositionType()){

                case 1://ARR
                    if(dispositionV8.getArrList() != null){
                        if(dispositionV8.getArrList().getArrListV8() != null){
                            for(ARRV8 arrV8: dispositionV8.getArrList().getArrListV8()){

                                if(arrV8.getDispindex() == dispositionV8FormParms.getDispindex()){

                                    dispositionV8Form = arrV8;

                                    formName = dispositionV8FormParms.getDispositionForm();
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2://MRR
                    if(dispositionV8.getArrList() != null){
                        if(dispositionV8.getMrrList().getMrrListV8() != null){
                            for(MRRV8 mrrV8: dispositionV8.getMrrList().getMrrListV8()){

                                if(mrrV8.getDispindex() == dispositionV8FormParms.getDispindex()){

                                    dispositionV8Form = mrrV8;

                                    formName = dispositionV8FormParms.getDispositionForm();
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 3://MRV
                    if(dispositionV8.getArrList() != null){
                        if(dispositionV8.getMrvList().getMrvListV8() != null){
                            for(MRVV8 mrvV8: dispositionV8.getMrvList().getMrvListV8()){

                                if(mrvV8.getDispindex() == dispositionV8FormParms.getDispindex()){

                                    dispositionV8Form = mrvV8;

                                    formName = dispositionV8FormParms.getDispositionForm();
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                }

                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
public String getFormName() {
    return formName;
}
public Object getDispositionV8Form() {
    return dispositionV8Form;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copyProperites` method from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html